# join/merge 2 files using just sed

Tags: sed

using just sed
i want to merge file 1 and 2 so it looks like file 3
with sed please if poss

file 1

```
bob
rob
kate
fred
mike
```

file 2

```
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
```

file  3

```
bob
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
rob
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
kate
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
fred
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
mike
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
```

Comment: you'll have to show what efforts you took to solve this by yourself.. did you check man page to see if there was an option to do this? searched online? tried some code? etc... that is what this site is all about, not to get handed code for free.. here's a hint, this is very very simple to solve if your sed supports `R` command

Comment: yes i did search online for it  but did not find how to with just sed

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** In `sed`:

```
sed 'R FiLe2' FiLe1
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With simple `paste` command.

```
paste -d"\n" Input_FiLe1  Input_FiLe2
```

***Solution 3rd:*** Adding `awk` command too now into solution:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR] RS $0}' FiLe1 FiLe2
```

Output will be as follows for both the above codes.

```
bob
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
rob
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
kate
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
fred
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
mike
http://www.somesite/play/episodes
```

You could take this command's output into file3 by concatenating `> file3` in case you need it.

Comment: hi thanks but the box i use has no option for paste just sed so please just sed if its possible

Comment: hi this box only has sed so if you know of a way with sed thanks

Comment: @bob, please check my very first solution now and let me know.

Comment: hi i only have sed this box has no paste or awk just sed

Comment: @bob, check my 1st solution please it is `sed` I added it before previous comment :)

Comment: sed: unsupported command R i change the R to small case r it works but i get to many urls under each name should be just one url under each name

Comment: @bob, I still can't believe your system doesn't have `paste` and `awk` what is O.S you are using? they should help you `paste` is the command which could help you easily here.

Comment: i  used 2 commands 1st with small case r  2nd remove dups line looks like sed 'r 2' 1 > 3 ;sed -i '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' 3